# 64-bit Java not recognized in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I set the render distance to Far in mine craft (latest version as of December 30 2011) it says that I need to install 64bit java.

**Interesting Information:**

- I am running Lion (Mac OS 10.7, latest version), 64-bit
- I have 64-bit Java installed as well as 32-bit (proved in the screenshot below)
- I ran a software update (to make sure I had the latest java version)
- I also ran a "force update" in Minecraft
- Restarted my machine several times
- After Googling I checked to see if 64-bit Java was at the top of the list, it was (in screenshot)

This is the error message that I am getting:

[image: 64-bit error]

Although I can still use the "Far" render distance, it is a tad choppy.

When I open Java Preferences (located in /Applications/Utilities) this is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling the 32-bit one?

Comment: I haven't; I'll give that a try right now.

Comment: When I disable the 32bit one, it also disables the 64bit one (leaving both checkboxes unchecked) and vice versa.  So it's impossible to disable one without disabling the other.

Comment: Hmm, can you give me the results of the Terminal command: `file "Minecraft.app/content/Mac OS/JavaApplicationStub"`? I want to see if the stub that starts Java is 32 or 64-bit.

Comment: `Minecraft.app/content/Mac OS/JavaApplicationStub: cannot open `Minecraft.app/content/Mac OS/JavaApplicationStub' (No such file or directory)`

Comment: Looking back now I already have my answer answered, but your command said "content" not "Contents"

Comment: Sorry, I got the path wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Minecraft on Mac OS X with 64-bit Java**

So you're a slave to warning messages and you want Minecraft to use 64-bit Java.  Here's how to do it on the command line.  These instructions were crafted on MacOS Lion, which should prefer 64-bit Java when possible (Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences).  These instructions assume the default Minecraft.app location, in the main /Applications folder.  I had a few tabs open, while I was sussing this out, including [an excellent forum post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/649868-guide-mac-support-101/), a post [on JavaApplicationStub](http://www.snailshell.de/blog/archives/2006/01/entry_37.html) bits, and the [official reference for CF keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html).

Here we go.

Swap out Minecraft's JavaApplicationStub for the current OS' version:

```
gzip /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub  # save a backup
cp /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

Then, add 64-bit architecture to Minecraft's possibilities:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :Java:JVMArchs:0 string 'x86_64'" /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Launch.  That should do it.  Watch out for creepers.  Have a nice day.

---

If everything goes wrong, here's how to roll back from here to your original configuration:

```
rm /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub
gunzip /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/JavaApplicationStub.gz
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :Java:JVMArchs:0" /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

I did not write this! [Source](http://fnaard.blogspot.com/2011/11/minecraft-on-mac-os-x-with-64-bit-java.html)

Comment: It worked!  There is a definite speed boost.  If I install a new version of Minecraft, will I have to redo these instructions?

Comment: Would I be allowed to use this code in a non-commercial program, made by myself?  I would, of course, link back to this article and give you credit.

Comment: @Alexy13 All that code does is copy the up-to-date Java launcher into your application bundle and sets a flag in the application's preferences to use 64-bit Java. So yes you can use it to modify any Java application bundle to run in 64-bit.

Comment: @Alexy13 I have not tested it myself so I don't know if you have to repeat the process when you update. I would think not. From my understanding you can use this "code" as much as you like. Though it's not my right to give this permission since I didn't write this. To be very sure you could ask the source article.

Comment: That didn't help. Still works in 32-bit mode.